# Is it possible to store cronjobs in laravel outside of app/Console/Kernel.php?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

The docu says, that every schedule has to be placed in `app/Console/Kernel.php`.
If I have more than - lets say - 50 cronjobs, this file gets very ugly.
I don´t see any way to create a structure here.
So it would be interesting to know, if it´s possible to store code like this:

`$schedule->command('emails:send --force')->daily();`

somewhere else, i.e. in a different class with another namespace.

Comment: Sure, just call it in the kernel then.

Comment: thats what this is all about: calling $schedule->command *NOT* inside the kernel..  i know i can call a function inside the command, but my intension is to outsource the whole $schedule->command.

Comment: I meant call the other function which registers the cronjobs in the kernel.

Comment: sorry, don´t understand, maybe you can do a small example snippet